# Prevent contenteditable="plaintext-only" div from creating a new line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div that is used as user input:
`<div id="chat-message-input" contenteditable="plaintext-only">`

When the user hits the enter key (and is **not** holding the shift key), the text from the user is submitted.

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {

       // User hits enter key and is not holding shift
       if (e.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey != 1) {

        //Click submit button
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();

        // Clear input field
        document.getElementById('chat-message-input').innerHTML='';
    };
</script>
```

**Problem: There is a brief moment where the div creates a new line because the enter key was pressed, before the content in the div is cleared.**

I only want a new line to be created under these circumstances:

1. The user's input text reaches the end of the line
2. The user holds shift and presses enter

Does anyone know how I can prevent a new line from being created given the above requirements?

Comment: What happens if you intercept keydown?

Comment: If I do onkeydown instead of onkeyup, the div creates a new line, and oddly stays there even with the code to clear the input field. So instead of the new line appearing momentarily, it is permanent.

Comment: I was thinking you'd have to intercept both and stop the standard action.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand why, but intercepting onkeydown in addition, worked like a charm. In the intercept, I added e.preventDefault() in the condition that Enter was the key being pressed down

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by A Haworth, I also intercepted onkeydown (in addition to onkeyup) and prevented the default. This seemed to work well.

```
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeydown = function(e) {
       // User hits enter key and is not holding shift
       if (e.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey != 1) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    };
```

This made the input field really solid, which is necessary for my real-time chat app. Thanks!